# How to detect selected element from each instance of select option in Angular 4?

Tags: angular, ngfor, angular4-forms, ngmodel

I have multiple template widgets which are dynamically created using *ngFor, [(ngModel)].
Now each of these templates consist one select-option list.

The problem is:

If I select option#1 from Template#1, other templates also get option#1. 
If I change option#2 in some other template, say Template#4, all templates get same option#2.

I tried to remove this problem like this:

i)

```
`*ngFor="let template of templateList, let i = index">
 <!-- truncated-->
 <select [(ngModel)] = "selectedOption[i]" (change)="myFunc()">
 <option *ngFor="let element of elements">{{element}}</option>
 </select>`
```

and also,

ii) `[(ngModel)] = "selectedOption[$index]"`

But in both cases I could not identify the "selectedOption" for individual Template in myFunc function.

```
`myFunc(){console.log(this.selectedOption);}`
```

#### dashboardConfig.component.html  ###

**This part to select no. of Widget**

```
 <div class="edit-dashboard">      
     <select [(ngModel)] = "widgetCounter" (change)="widgetCountFunc()">
        <option *ngFor="let i of ArrayOfNumbersForWidget">{{i}}</option>
     <select>
 </div>
```

**this part to create widgets**

```
  <div class="widget-area" *ngFor="let i of widgetObjList ">    

    <select [(ngModel)]="selectedOption (change)="selectedOptForThisWidget()">
         <option *ngFor="let opt of ListOfOpts" [value]="opt">{{opt}}</option>
     </select>
  </div>
```

#### dashboardConfig.component.ts ###

```
 widgetCountFunc(){
     this.ListOfOpts = ArrayMaker(this.widgetCounter);
           }
```

> ArrayMaker() this part creates an array of selected number, not elaborated

So the issue occurs with     `[(ngModel)] = "selectedOption"`.

1) How to select individual option for each of the widgets?
   e.g. For Widget #1 -> Option #2; Widget #2 -> Option #5 etc.

2) How to show the pre-selected options for each widget through 
    `"selectedOption"` assuming we have a json file of the widgets and corresponding options?

Comment: option is not  a template, you can't use indexes there but a model can be used to bind the template.

Comment: yes, using index is not helpful. cause I need to select element from 2nd ngFor. But already using ngModel. could you please suggest how to use that to get individual option.

Comment: Your question is not very clear... Could you give some more info?

Comment: Im running a loop which can create multiple widgets. Each widget holds a select list. If I select option1 in widget1, then widget 2...n is also getting updated with option1. But my target is to provide different option to individual widget e.g. widget 1.. opt.5, widget 2 ... opt.3.. so on.

Comment: Could you set up a plunker or something like so we don't have to begin from scratch. It will be very helpful

Comment: I would take some time to upload it in plunker. I need to clear my concept here: in multiple instances of same directive(i.e. select), scope is not isolated. So how to do that scope isolation in Angular 4?

Comment: Does `Please suggest me to do the needful here to` actually mean `How to`? Otherwise your final sentence made no sense.

Comment: Yes I meant , 'how to'

Comment: @Vega , please seethe minimal code here